# В сафари не работает регулярка

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, safari

```
st = st.replace(/(?<=^|\s)[\p{L}]{1,3}(?=\s)/gu, '$&&nbsp;')
```

В сафари ошибка: Invalid regular expression.
В остальных браузерах всё ок.

Comment: Скорее всего ретроспективная проверка ``(?<=^|\s)`` в вашей версии Safari еще не поддерживается. Ее поддержка была [добавлена в версии 16.4 (release 27 Mar 2023)](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).